# How to enable session and set session timeout in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-security

I am new to Spring Security and I am working on a login, logout, and session timeout feature. I have configured my code by referring to [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#sessionManagement%28%29) document. My code looks below:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/admin/**")
        .access("hasRole('ROLE_USER')").and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").and().csrf();
    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired");
}
```

**Override the class AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer**

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer;

public class SpringSecurityInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public boolean enableHttpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

I need clarification on whether I am doing it right, if it looks good, then where I need to setup the session timeout. I am doing it fully based on annotation.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was able to solve above issue by adding below config in web.xml only. any better way will be accepted.

```
 <session-config>
    <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Answer (score 35):

If you are using [JavaConfig](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/) and do not want to use XML you can create a `HttpSessionListener` and use `getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval()`, then in the `Initializer` add the listener in `onStartup()`:

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("session created");
        event.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(15);
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
       System.out.println("session destroyed");
    }
}
```

Then in the Initializer:

```
@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    super.onStartup(servletContext);
    servletContext.addListener(new SessionListener());
}
```

Comment: You can also add the listener as a bean, in case you start up your application in a different way.

Comment: super.onStartup(servletContext); its not taking showing error in intializer

Comment: Hi @munilvc  session is create onStartup is fine.. when trying track user session, the session time should start after Logged in right

Comment: in which class should i use void onStartup function

Answer (score 15):

When using application.properties set property `server.session.timeout=` value is in seconds.

Comment: `server.servlet.session.timeout=` helped me. List of common properties: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 11):

Different ways to configure session timeout time(maxInactiveInterval) in spring security.

**1. By addinng session config in web.xml(from raju vaishnav's answer)**

**2. By creating implementation of HttpSessionListener and adding it to servlet context.(from munilvc's answer)**

#### 3. By registering your custom AuthenticationSuccessHandler in spring security configuration, and setting session maximum inactive interval in onAuthenticationSuccess method.

This implementation has advantages

1. On login success, You can set different value of maxInactiveInterval for different roles/users.
2. On login success, you can set user object in session, hence user object can be accessed in any controller from session.

Disadvantage: You can not set session timeout for ANONYMOUS user(Un-authenticated user)

Create AuthenticationSuccessHandler Handler

```java
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler
{

    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException 
    {
        Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
        if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN"))
        {
            request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
        }
        else
        {
            request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(120);
        }
        //Your login success url goes here, currently login success url="/"
        response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath());
    }
}
```

Register success handler

In Java Config way

```java
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/app/admin/*").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/app/user/*", "/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and().formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("userName")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .successHandler(new MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler())
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
        .and().logout()
            .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
        .and().csrf().disable();

    http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login?expired=true");
}
```

In xml config way

```xml
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired">
    <csrf disabled="true"/>

    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/app/admin/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/user/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

    <form-login 
        login-page="/login"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" 
        username-parameter="userName"
        password-parameter="password" />

    <logout invalidate-session="false" success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler"/>

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/login?expired=true">
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management>
 </http>
 
 <beans:bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.pvn.mvctiles.configuration.MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
```

Working code is available in [my github repository](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/)
Working code is available in two forms

[1. XML config way of implementation](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/springsecurity-auth-success-handler-xmlconfig)

[2. JAVA config way of implementation](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/stackoverflow-answer-reference/tree/master/springsecurity-auth-success-handler-javaconfig)

If you want to have automatic logout feature and timer which displays when session is about to expire, if user is filling form but not submitted then user can extend session by clicking on keep session alive button.
If you want to implement auto logout refer [stack overflow answer on auto logout on session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57598264/2825798). Hope this will help.

Answer (score 7):

In your application properties use
**`server.servlet.session.timeout=1m`** (If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.)

By default it is 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I handled it inside subclass of [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.html)
You can get username by -

```
obtainUsername(request);
```

and apply user checks and set time out accordingly, like-

```
if(username.equalsIgnoreCase("komal-singh-sisodiya@xyz.com")) 
        {
        logger.debug("setting timeout 15 min");
        request.getSession(false).setMaxInactiveInterval(15*60);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below in `application.proprites`

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
@EnableJdbcHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 84600)
```