# How to define which CookieSerializer is injected into SpringHttpSessionConfiguration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I have a Spring Boot 1.5 application, in which I've added Spring-Session in the pom.xml.  I am instantiating 2 instances of the `CookieSerializer` class, for my own needs in a configuration class.

But when the application launches, I get the following error message:

```
Parameter 0 of method setCookieSerializer in org.springframework.session.config.annotation.web.http.SpringHttpSessionConfiguration required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - authCookieSerializer: defined by method 'authCookieSerializer' in class path resource [nextgen/config/SpringHttpSessionConfig.class]
    - sessionCookieSerializer: defined in BeanDefinition defined in class path resource [nextgen/config/SpringHttpSessionConfig.class]
```

How do I use SpringSession if I want to use the `CookieSerializer` bean for other things as well?  Am I forced to define a `CookieSerializer` as a `@Primary` bean just to be autowired into the SpringSession config class?

My config class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringHttpSessionConfig {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringHttpSessionConfig.class);

    @Bean(name="authCookieSerializer")
    public CookieSerializer authCookieSerializer() {
            DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
            serializer.setCookieName("auth"); 
            serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$");
            serializer.setCookiePath("/");
            return serializer;
    }

    @Bean(name="sessionClassicCookieSerializer")
    public CookieSerializer sessionCookieSerializer() {
            DefaultCookieSerializer serializer = new DefaultCookieSerializer();
            serializer.setCookieName("JSESSIONID"); 
            serializer.setDomainNamePattern("^.+?\\.(\\w+\\.[a-z]+)$");
            serializer.setCookiePath("/classic");
            return serializer;
    }
```

application.properties:

```
spring.session.store-type=hash-map
```

Am I missing something obvious?  Or rather, what definition of the CookieSerializer do I need for the SpringSession configuration, and how can I specify it for the Spring Session configuration bean without it being the "primary" bean?  Or do I have no choice but to define the "primary" CookieSerializer as the one I want injected into the `SpringHttpSessionConfiguration` class?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this answer is what you mean

I recently encountered a similar problem, my application had 2 login pages for 2 different user types and needed to configure different session cookie max age for those 2 login pages.

One method I'm thinking of like you is to create 2 different DefaultCookieSerializers instances. However, Spring doesn't seem to allow that

Luckily I found an alternative.

By registering your custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` in spring security configuration, and setting session maximum inactive interval in `onAuthenticationSuccess` method.

You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57598611/5718493