# How to implement session management in spring with time period 30 minute

Tags: spring-mvc, session

In my post i have tried simple login functionality whether the user is valid or not. if the user is valid i have to implement session feature  for 30 min,
if the user is not doing anything till 30 min how to make him to logout, he has to login with username and password. can anyone explain how i can implement session management in spring mvc with the above requirement session time for 30 min ?

**AppConfig**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:spring.properties")    
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.spring")
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");    
        return viewResolver;
    }
    @Bean
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource rb = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        rb.setBasenames(new String[] { "messages/messages", "messages/validation" });
        return rb;
    }    
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }    
}
```

**AppInitializer**

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

**Contoller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticateUserLogin", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView authenticateUserLogin(@ModelAttribute("loginForm") @Validated User user, BindingResult result, Model model, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

        if(user.getEmail().equals("abc") && user.getPassword().equals("123")){
        return new ModelAndView("Dashboard", "name", model);
        }
        else
        {
        return new ModelAndView("Login", "name", model);
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36795678/how-to-enable-session-and-set-session-timeout-in-spring-security) answer it's explained how to do it via java config or xml config.

Comment: in that example session creation and destroy is there, i was not found any session timeout constraint over there

Comment: Have you checked the accepted answer, the one that says that in order to set the session timeout you need to add the following in your web.xml (or the any alternative, depending on how you configure your app):

`<session-config>
          <session-timeout>20</session-timeout>
</session-config>`