# Redirect user to login page on timeout Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring Core version 4.1.6 and Spring security 4.0.1.

I want to redirect user to login page on timeout.

So far after some research, I implemented `ApplicationListener<HttpSessionDestroyedEvent>` and I can now successfully intercept timeouts and logouts.

I have `HttpSessionDestroyedEvent` object in `onApplicationEvent` function. This object dont seem to have any method from where I can redirect user or return login model object. My question is how can I redirect user to login page?

I have seen [this url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775651/how-to-make-automatically-log-out-with-spring-security) but it doesn't intercepts timeouts. My question is more focused towards timeouts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make automatically log out with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775651/how-to-make-automatically-log-out-with-spring-security)

Comment: I have seen this url but it dont intercepts timeouts. My question is more focused towards timeouts.

Comment: may be in spring security.xml i have to add some extra tags in <form-login> for registering SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler with application?

Comment: Not in form-login, in the logout section of spring security Try the code from my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches for this. first you can use spring security auto config in your `applicationContext.xml` by setting `login-page` it will automatically redirect not logged-in users reaching secured routes (like /userReged/**) to that certain login-page :

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/userReged/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <security:form-login
            login-page="/"
            default-target-url="/somePage"
            authentication-failure-url="/user/logfailed?error"
            username-parameter="userName"
            password-parameter="userPassword" />
    <security:logout
            logout-success-url="/?logout"/>
</security:http>
```

one other way is to check user being logged-in in your controller manually in specific route :

```
@RequestMapping("/somePage")
public String getSomePage(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {

    Principal principal = request.getUserPrincipal();
    if (principal != null) {

        User activeUser = userService.getUserByPhone(principal.getName());
        // ...

    } else { // user is not authenticated
        System.out.println("user is not authenticated to proceed the somePage!!!!!!!");
        return "redirect:/";
    }
}
```

In order to set timeout for spring security you can put this in your `web.xml` :

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        1440
        <!--mins-->
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

now if you want to redirect clients on exact timeout you can refresh the page automatically in client side in some intervals.