# How to redirect using spring security session time out?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm using spring boot 2.2.0.M2 spring security this package version is 5.2.0, my project fronted is done in vuejs 2.6.10

What I want to archive seems very simple, when spring security session is time out i want to redirect ( force browser ) to go to URL http://localhost:8080/

What I was trying till now is:

I have created configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/")
                        .defaultSuccessUrl("/admin#/timetable")
                    .permitAll()
                .and().logout()
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(1)
                .expiredUrl("/")
                .expiredSessionStrategy(event -> event.getResponse().sendRedirect("/"));
                // this supoose to work right?
 }
}
```

and in my application.properties I have added for testing purpouses:

```
# Server
server.servlet.session.timeout=1m
```

And after one minute nothing happens.

So I thought that maybe something is wrong and session is not timeout so I've run my application in debug mode and I putted break point in

```
package org.springframework.security.web.session;
...
public class HttpSessionEventPublisher implements HttpSessionListener 
{
  ...
  public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
  //my break point
  }
}
```

And after one minute I'm in, debugger stopped in sessionDestroyed method so session is no longer exist.

About my UI, I'm using vuejs embedded in thyme leaf page:

[image]

So my question is do You know how to force browser to reload my application or redirect to http://localhost:8080/ when spring security session is expired (timeout) ?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27775651/how-to-log-out-automatically-with-spring-security OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45812484/redirect-user-to-login-page-on-timeout-spring-security

Comment: You cannot. VueJS is, as the name implies, JavaScript and that won't handle a redirect very well (or actually the browser is handling that redirect). So unless you are doing something fancy with JavaScript (and maybe a custom response code or whatever) it won't work.